# PHP get data from DB not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysql-select-db

Can you figure out my code? All the code does is: **No database selected** It won't get the data from the db. The server os is Ubuntu or OS X. I been pulling my hair out for hours.

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("hit-counter");

$sql_get_count = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM hit_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

if($sql_get_count === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_count)) { 
    print_r($row);
} 
?>
```

I try this, it does the same

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("hit-counter");

$sql_get_count = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM hit_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

if($sql_get_count === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_count)) { 
    print_r($row);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Is there any error? if so then please share it too.

Comment: Mixing `mysqli and mysql` in your code!!!

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g.php on line 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have an error in your code. You use `mysqli_` function to connect the server but you use a deprecated function `mysql_` to select the database.

Try this code:

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db("hit-counter");
```

Another option when using `mysqli_` is to select the database you want during connecting to the server:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g.php on line 8

Comment: `$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db("hit-counter", $db);`

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g.php on line 3`
No database selected

Comment: Follow my comment below about `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. You have to notice which one you use.

Comment: sorry, you figure it out! thanks man :)

Comment: In `mysqli_`, the connection comes first, not last `mysqli_select_db($db, "hit-counter");`

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention database name:try this

```
      <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","654321","testV2") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));

  // Write query

  $strSQL = "SELECT id FROM did  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

  // Execute the query.

  $query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
  while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
echo $result["id"]."
  ";
  }

  // Close the connection
  mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g.php on line 7`

Comment: @TateA I have changed the code.It works for me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interchange the `mysql` and `mysqli` functions, please modify your `mysql_select_db` to `mysqli_select_db`.

Answer (score 0):

I will not go over the errors everyone else has pointed out.  But, I will mention one that no one has.  I think the - character in your database name will also cause problems.  You should enclose the database name in back ticks.  The back tick is this ` character, most likely the far left key above the TAB key.  If you had error reporting turned on, or looked at your php error log, you would have seen the error.